# Translation of like, like when, as, as if

Tags: sentence-translation

How do you say the following in Latin?

1. That place is like a paradise.
2. Reading is like travelling with the mind.
3. Love is like when you use a credit card: you are not aware that most likely you will spend a lot of money.
4. As a citizen, you have rights.
5. As you wish.
6. As you already know, he will not come.
7. You look as if you had seen a ghost. (Counterfactual concerning the past)
8. You speak as if you were not going to come back. (Counterfactual concerning the future)

For the latter I have seen an example with *tamquam* + future active participle. In *De Brevitate Vitae*, it says

> Tamquam semper victuri vivitis - You live as if you were going to live forever.

Is there another structure for that? In this case the part with participle has no verb (only *semper victuri*). Does it have to be always that way?

Also there is a quote with quasi + future active participle:

> Disce quasi semper victurus; vive quasi cras moriturus - Learn as if you were going to live forever; live as if you were going to die tomorrow

Is there another possible connector?

Comment: Eventually there is no need for ... what is "as" anyway, a conjunction? I mean, English uses many prepositions to make up for its loss of the inflections. Even if Latin had a near synonym--I'm as curious as you--I guess it will often be left out, or is baked in with the word. So "as a citizen" is probably realized as ablative or vocative inflection, similar to *citizen rights*. Indeed, *als* exists similarly but not equivalently in German as well, as Germanic had already lost some cases. I've started to cp Greek relative pronouns, and it seems L *-alis, qualis* may be correlated to *as, like*.

Comment: Point in case, *like when* is almost redundant. The usual aphorism is phrased "Love is when you finish each others sentences", and there's also "Happiness is a warm gun", "sex is like driving--safety comes first", etc.. However, I'm aware it's a collocation, idem G *wie wenn*, and it feels a lot like *quasi* which is also composed of two syllables (not to commit to much to a grammatic interpretation).

Comment: take a look at the last collumns here https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:Latin_correlatives

Answer (score 4):

There are a number of ways to express this kind of comparison in Latin, and no one solution will be sufficient.
The simplest word is probably *sicut* or *ut*.
For example, you can insert the comment "as everyone knows" in Latin as *sicut omnes sciunt* (e.g. Cicero, *In Q. Caecilium* 41).
"As you wish" can be translated as *ut vis* (common in Plautus).

If you want to say "X is like Y", then I suggest *similis* or *par*.
*Locus ille Elysii similis/par est* would be a good way to describe a paradise.

If you want to add a counterfactual tone with something like the English "as if", I recommend using *quasi*.
For example, I might translate:

> You speak as if you were not going to come back.
>   *Loqueris quasi numquam rediturus.*

As you have noticed, it is often most convenient to use participles for things like this in Latin.
Participles are good at setting up circumstances under which something is done; e.g. *edens ausculto* is "I listen while I eat".
Adding *quasi* or *tamquam* can bring the desired counterfactual tone.
Another similar word is *proinde*, which seems to be a common choice when a subordinate clause is used instead of a participle; see [Lewis and Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=proinde&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for examples.

If you want help with translating a specific sentence nicely, please ask a separate question.
Your question is somewhat broad, so I won't try to go through all individual examples in detail.
Overall, my suggestion is to consider the words *(sic)ut, tamquam, proinde, similis, par, quasi*.

Comment: My heart is so happy to know that this exchange even happened in this day and age. I love learning. Thank you. God bless.

Comment: Talking about *similis*, note it can take both the genitive and the dative; the genitive is preferred for perfect resemblance (e.g. "similis patris"), and in expressions like "veri similis", "similis mei/tui/...".